# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 12 \\b]([^.(|[]+)

Tags: java, regex

Unclosed character class near index 12 \b]([^.(|[]+) ^

The regex above works fine, however it does not work on java and i cant detect what is the problem that causing it.

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to escape the opening bracket in your character class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape opening and closing square bracket like `\b\\]\\(\\[^.(|\\[\\]+)` (this is just your remaining regex and not whole regex i believe) since you specify meta character within square brackets and has a special meaning while defining regex.

Answer (score 0):

To make the regex working in Java use:  `\b\]([^.(|\[]+)`

The Java Regex String is:

```
"\\b\\]([^.(|\\[]+)"
```

Comment: I have remove the `^` at the end, since it is most likely part of the exception output which points out the position with problem, not part of the original regex.